# Python telebot кнопки команды не работают

Tags: python, telebot

Я написал простенький код на питоне, импорт telebot, но есть огромная проблема, в коде у меня созданы кнопки и команды '/', ну и команда просто по тексту, но вот есть одна проблема, когда запускаю, я не могу вести сначала команды, надо нажать на кнопку который запраграмирован, а потом уже можно будет использовать команды, а когда к примеру я не нажимаю с самого начал на кнопки а просто введу команды, то иногда он не работает, а иногда может быть работает, но когда работает то кнопки перестают работать

```
import telebot
import time
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('key')

#Начальные кнопки под клавиатурой
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
bn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Получить фото')
bn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Профиль')
bn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Пополнить баланс')
markup.row(bn2, bn1)
markup.row(bn3)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет <b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>', reply_markup = markup, parse_mode = 'html')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, on_click)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def help(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'С удовольствием вам помогу')

@bot.message_handler()
def info(message):
    if message.text == 'Как дела?':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Нормально, у вас как?")

#функции для работы всяких кома
def on_click(message):
    if message.text == 'Получить фото':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Фото будет отправлено через ...')
        time.sleep(1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '3')
        time.sleep(1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '2')
        time.sleep(1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '1')
        time.sleep(1)


bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

Смотрите, когда я нажимаю на кнопку под комментарием, оно работает, и после того как введу какие то команды, так же работает.

Но вот когда я не нажимаю в самом начале кнопку под клавиатурой, а сразу ввожу какую то команду, то почему то команда не работает, и потом когда нажимаю кнопку под клавиатурой так же не работает

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Смотрите, когда я нажимаю на кнопку под комментарием, оно работает, и после того как введу какие то команды, так же работает.

Comment: Но вот когда я не нажимаю в самом начале кнопку под клавиатурой, а сразу ввожу какую то команду, то почему то команда не работает, и потом когда нажимаю кнопку под клавиатурой так же не работает

Comment: Исправил, проверьте